# Problem using the CRAN "gapminder" package

Tags: r, timezone, package

I tried downloading the R package "gapminder" but I am unable to use the data from the package. I think it's because I'm receiving these error messages in the console.

Here is the code I inputed:

```
install.packages("gapminder")
library("gapminder")
data("gapminder")
```

And here is what I got:

```
Warning message:
In format.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x), ...) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2019c.1.0/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris'
```

and

```
Warning message:
In data("gapminder") : data set ‘gapminder’ not found
```

Is it related to my current time zone? I'm in France. If so, how can I modify it to be able to use the data in the package normally?

Comment: How is that timezone being set? You might not be doing it explicitly, something in your OS is ... corrupting it? That looks invalid from anything I'm familiar with. I would expect your TZ to be `"Europe/Paris"` (found here with `grep("Paris", OlsonNames(), value=TRUE)`).

Comment: What does `sessionInfo()` show when you first open R?

Comment: @MrFlick Here is what I get with sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.15.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base   
```